# Is WEC (Windows Embedded Compact) development supported in VS 2013?

Tags: compact-framework, windows-ce, visual-studio-2013, windows-embedded-compact

I've downloaded VS 2013, hoping it would make it easier for porting our Windows CE / CF app, specifically easier for debugging. My worst problem is not being able to connect to the emulator from VS 2008 ([How do I get the Emulator on the same network as my PC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19260075/how-do-i-get-the-emulator-on-the-same-network-as-my-pc)) - and previously, in XP Mode / VS 2003, it wasn't even feasible to make the attempt (after several concussions incurred bashing my head against the wall).

I was hoping there would be a better process for that in VS 2013. But, based on what I see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/vstudio/dn250998.aspx there may be no support at all (yet?) for WEC.

Am I really stuck with no WEC support in VS 2013, as it appears?

Comment: What version of WEC are you using? 
Have you looked at ctacke's response here?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16541980/developing-applications-for-windows-embedded-compact-2013

Comment: Currently using the legacy Windows CE / Compact Framework; I was hoping upgrading to WEC would make things easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Development for devices running Windows Embedded Compact 2013 is supported in Visual Studio 2012.
Development for devices running older versions of Windows CE (5.0, 6.0), Windows Embedded Compact 7, Windows Mobile, Windows Embedded Handhelds is supported only in Visual Studio 2008.